# How to solve equations involving floor function

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

$x = \lfloor a * y\rfloor$

where $x$ and $y$ are variables and $a$ is a constant.

What is the feasible space of $y$?

Comment: Welcome! Take a [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour). You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4790120/edit)): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, _etc._; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: It would be great if you included the domain of possible values of $x,y$ Are $x,y$ real numbers? Are they rational? If they are natural, then the floor function makes little difference

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but you can rewrite your equation as saying that $x$ is the unique integer such that
$$
ay \leq x < ay + 1
$$
so in turn, if $a$ is positive,
$$
\frac{x}{a} \geq y > \frac{x-1}{a}
$$
and if $a$ is negative,
$$
\frac{x}{a} \leq y < \frac{x-1}{a}
$$
which may be what you're looking for.

Note: if $a = 0$ then $x = 0$ so I'm assuming $a \ne 0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!